# Bulk update datatype of a column in all relevant tables

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

An example of some tables with the column I want to change.

```
+--------------------------------------+------------------+------+
| ?column?                        | column_name      | data_type |
|--------------------------------------+------------------+------|
| x.articles                      | article_id       | bigint    |
| x.supplier_articles             | article_id       | bigint    |
| x.purchase_order_details        | article_id       | bigint    |
| y.scheme_articles               | article_id       | integer   |
....
There are some 50 tables that have the column.
```

I want to change the `article_id` column from a numeric data type to a textual data type. It is found across several tables. Is there anyway to update them all at once ? Information schema is readonly so I cannot do an update on it. Other than writing inidividual alter statements for all the tables, is there a better way to do it ?

Comment: "*from a numeric data type to a textual data type.*" - why? You should **never** store numbers in a text (or varchar) column. That is a _huge_ mistake. But you will have to drop all foreign keys (`alter table ... drop constraint ...`)  then change the data type (`alter table ... alter column ... type`) and re-add the foreign keys. But again: **never** store numbers in text columns.

Comment: I think that is obvious. I need to change from numeric to text since the id's  now can be textual in nature. Hence the change. Also why would I need to drop foregin keys if I change in all tables. FK's dont care about type; only that they are unique right ?

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/ck26t_SF

Comment: Hmm.. Ok I understand. But its not an issue in my case. That column wont be a foreign key.